# "Stack is empty" in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I am writing a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. It consists of a `MessagesController` that calls a `LuisDialog` using `await Conversation.SendAsync...`.

Some scenarios trigger an exception with this message:

> Stack is empty

I found the place in the source code of the Bot Framework where it is triggered:

```
  134         public static T Peek<T>(this IList<T> stack)
  135         {
  136             if (stack.Count == 0)
  137             {
  138                 throw new InvalidOperationException("Stack is empty");
  139             }
  140 
  141             return stack[stack.Count - 1];
  142         }
```

However, I cannot figure out how exactly it is triggered. When debugging line by line, the code seems to work fine (there's a lot of code, and it goes through all of it).

When just letting it run without breakpoints, it crashes with this exception.

My `await Conversation.SendAsync` is wrapped into a try/catch and this is how I catch the exception.

I couldn't figure out more about which part of code exactly causes the exception.

Do you have any idea what could cause the "Stack is empty" message?

**Later update:**

Some time later, I started getting the `Stack is Empty` exceptions in another piece of code, and I made sure everything is `async`ed and `await`ed:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(UserProfileStep1);
}

public async Task UserProfileStep1(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> original)
{
    string originalMessage = (string)await original; // <== the exception occurs here
```

Turns out that in that particular case, it was because I used `context.Forward` and tried to pass a `string` object into it, while it only supports `IMessageActivity` objects.

Comment: Are you creating a proactive conversation somewhere?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue occasionally also - and yes, I am creating proactive conversations. Is there a timing issue I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like you are missing an await operator somewhere. I ran into this exception before (even with the same issue) when calling an external API an wasn't awaiting for it to complete, so when i was debugging i was giving time, but in real-time the bot was faster than the API. I would need to look at your code for giving more info

Comment: Weirdly, now I have the Stack is Empty message happening at this line: `string originalMessage = (string)await original;`, where `original` is the `IAwaitable<object>` from the dialog function arguments.

Comment: Maybe it is a nonsense but have you tried to write it like this: var originalMessage = await original as string

Comment: Solved this problem by removing some of the await processes on before the line using the context making them synchronous

Answer (score 0):

> `context.Done<object>(null);`

Use this in the last of StartAsync.